# How to caputure page level events on a user control on that same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it posible to caputure button click event that is on a page, to a  User Control which is with in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass a parent's button click event to a child, you can do it.

In the User Control, make a method called `HandleParentButtonClick`(passing necessary parameters).  In the parent's OnClick event, call the User Control's `HandleParentButtonClick` method.

Comment: Thanks. i added funtion to user control  and called it from parent. But i need to capture event, so that the user control should treat it as a event for itself. is that possible. right now, its acting as a function call.

Comment: You can do that as well.  Look up delegates and custom events.  It's not much different from just calling a separate method, though.